# Draw on a Canvas from another Class

Tags: android, canvas, view, android-canvas

I am trying to draw multiple rectangles from an Asynctask on my view. In my MainActivity i call the View as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View bouncingBallView = new BouncingBallView2(this);
        setContentView(bouncingBallView);
        bouncingBallView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Then in my `BouncingBallView` i create the canvas:

```
public class BouncingBallView2 extends View {
    private Box box;

    final BouncingBallView2 context = this;
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;


    // Constructor
    public BouncingBallView2(Context context) {
        super(context);

        box = new Box(Color.BLACK);  // ARGB


        task=new PackagesPosition();
        task.execute();
    }

    // Called back to draw the view. Also called after invalidate().
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draw the components
        box.draw(canvas);


        invalidate();  // Force a re-draw
    }

    // Called back when the view is first created or its size changes.
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {

        box.set(0, 0, w, h);

    }
```

As you can see I call the `AsyncTask` class, which is also within the BouncingBall.  The `AsyncTask` gets a list of boxes with four values for each box: `x,y,width,height`.

The box class works as follows:

```
public class Box {
    int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    private Paint paint;  // paint style and color
    private Rect bounds;


    public Box(int color) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        bounds = new Rect();

    }

    public void set(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        xMin = x;
        xMax = x + width - 1;
        yMin = y;
        yMax = y + height - 1;
        // The box's bounds do not change unless the view's size changes
        bounds.set(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
    }


    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(bounds, paint);


    }
}
```

I don't know how to add a box from the `AsyncTask` because i don't have direct access to the Canvas, do you know how should i proceed? 
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: you can have a setter and getter in the view class and then call invalidate() to draw contents.

Comment: You can pass reference of canvas through constructor of the AsyncTask or use interface to get position from Activity

Comment: @Raghunandan, how can I do that? I'm a little bit lost,  I just started using the Canvas

Comment: Move all your drawing and the paint object initialization to view class. You can then use a setter and getter and call appropriate methods. Then finall you want to refresh the draw by calling invalidate() on your view

Comment: @Raghunandan, if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it, the method worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to inject the canvas through the constructor of your `Box` class. Personally I would not paint outside a `View`, though. I suggest moving your painting inside `BouncingBallView2` and add a method that is called from your `AsyncTask`. This method would control the animation sequence and do an `invalidate()` on the view.